# .htaccess not working in xamp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have PHP project on my `localhost`, which is running a XAMPP stack.

I want to remove the `.php` extension from all user-facing URLs.

I've tried using Apache's `mod_rewrite` in an `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^locations(/.*)?$ poet.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

But it is "not working".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: @Abhishek I have seen this post when i google but this step is not working so finally i decided to ask question

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]

Comment: when i use this i found 404 page

Comment: @VivekMishra If you came across relevant questions or other material that did not help it is a good idea to state that in your question. This way people will know what you tried and someone may spot the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Note: don't forgot to change RewriteBase path if your project folder is not on root.

Comment: don't forgot to change RewriteBase path if your project folder is not on root. i can't understand this. its my first htaccess

Comment: it means if your project is on root of htdocs folder then use the above code as it is, but if your project is not on root of htdocs then please specify the path upto your project folder ....                                                              e.g. suppose your project is inside htdocs/projects/demoproject1 ......  then RewriteBase path will be like this                                        RewriteBase   /projects/demoproject1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code solution your problems

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
           RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
     </IfModule>
```

Comment: I also enable AllowOverride All from my http.conf

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule in your project directory,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```